# Store block of HTML as jquery variable and copy into another div

Tags: jquery, variables

I need to store a block of html code from one element as a jquery variable and then copy it into another element upon click. This is the code I use:

```
var $regForm = $('#regForm').html();

$('#btn-signup').tap(function(){
    $('#register').css({'marginLeft':'0px'});
    $('#register .ext').html($regForm);
});
```

When viewing the updated source I can see that the code is copied into the div correctly, but the problem is the elements do not show up on screen and I can't figure out why. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#btn-signup').tap(function(){
    $('#register').css({'marginLeft':'0px'});
    $('#regForm').clone().attr('id', 'regForm2').appendTo($('#register .ext'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('#regForm').clone().appendTo('#register .ext');
```

Comment: not working... when viewing the updated source it hasn't even copied.